# What are the pitfalls of Cassandra materialised views and IN queries?

Tags: events, cassandra, data-modeling, materialized-views

Let's say I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE events (         
  stream_id text,         
  type text,         
  data text,         
  timestamp timestamp,         
  PRIMARY KEY (stream_id, timestamp)
);
```

The request pattern is that I need to get all events by `stream_id`.
e.g. `SELECT * FROM events WHERE stream_id = 'A-1';`

Then I need to get all events given a set of `type`s. So I create a MV:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW events_by_type AS
  SELECT * FROM events
  WHERE type IS NOT NULL AND
  timestamp IS NOT NULL 
  PRIMARY KEY (type, stream_id, timestamp)
  WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC);
```

The request is like
`SELECT * FROM events_by_type WHERE type IN ('T1', 'T2);`

What are the pitfalls with this query patterns and data model?
If any, is it possible to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only pitfall I can think of that you may hit is the consistency with the view is not reflected in the consistency level of the write to the base table. So if you need stronger consistency (quorum on reads & writes) you may run into issues.

One concern is that your partitions are unbounded. On current versions if your building larger than 100mb or so partitions you can start having misc performance issues (works, but will sometimes require GC tuning to keep things moving). This is improving recently but you should break up your partitions some. i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE events (         
  stream_id text,
  time_bucket text,
  type text,         
  data text,         
  timestamp timestamp,         
  PRIMARY KEY ((stream_id, time_bucket), timestamp)
);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW events_by_type AS
  SELECT * FROM events WHERE
    type IS NOT NULL AND
    time_bucket IS NOT NULL AND
    timestamp IS NOT NULL 
PRIMARY KEY ((type, time_bucket), stream_id, timestamp)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC);
```

It adds a little complexity in your `time_bucket` needs to be known. You can either predefine the buckets to something like daily (ie `2016-10-10 00:00:00`) or create a new table that maps the possible time_buckets for a type or stream_id.

Comment: Thanks for very detailed answer. Given the changes you suggest how do I query all events by stream_id? Or this time_bucket only affects how I write data? Regarding consistency, you saying that write quorum to base table does not guarantee a read quorum from MV. I'm ok with MV being eventually consistent with base table.

Comment: asking for "all" events for a series I would recommend spark or as the dataset grows it may take too long. If your asking for all the events in a time period,  you can iterate through the time buckets in that range and do a query per bucket. So if your time bucket is YYYY-MM (monthly) and you want the year end report, add data to your processing one month at a time. Its drastically more complex but having an additional table that contains the time_buckets for the stream id can save you wasted reads. https://academy.datastax.com/demos/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling is relevant.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This may also be an case where an old fashioned secondary index is a reasonable choice. Assuming there is a reasonably bounded but not tiny number of types a secondary index could work OK. (If there are only a tiny number of different types then you may also run into problems with large partitions in the materialized view.)

Comment: There is approximately a hundred of types. Is it ok? I will take a look at using of secondary index. Thanks.

Comment: Secondary index in this scenario would have same issues as MV only you cannot work around it with bucketing. It will create a partition for each type that will grow unbounded. A 2i on time series data will very rarely work out.